# mix left-add multiplier, school book algo for signed multiplication

Tags: algorithm, assembly, multiplication

I am trying to produce an efficient extended multiplication in assembly language. Although my code works well, I have some issue with a signed multiplication. Presently, my number are based on the two complement method, I convert my number to positive make my multiplication and then adjust the final size. It works but a little dummy, as it necessitates extra copy. I opened a hardware book and I discovers the shift-add multiplier which run well for signed number.

So considering I work on 4 bit number for input, I get a 8 bit for output. I want to make the multiplication -3 * 3, with a left shift binary multiplier, I have :

```
                     1101  // -3
               X     0011  // 3 
         -----------------------
         11111101 // I make the first x with sign extension
         1111101 // I make the a second x with sign extension,
         000000  // 0 no sign extension
         00000   // Later I will subtract this in case "of", as in book
         -----------------------
         11110111 <----------- final addition I get -9 OK it works
```

So now let's go for an hybrid solution with school book algo, I decompose my first number
1101 to 11 and 01, and the same for 0011 to 00 and 11. If I rewrite my algo, as we learnt at school:

```
           11 01
           00 11
           ---------------
           00 11  (unsigned mul 01 x 11 gives 00 11) , no sign extension
        10 01     (11 * 11  gives 10 01)                             
        --------------------
        10 01 11 (sum)
     11 10 01 11 (I made a sign extension until 8 bit)
     00 00 00 00 (the last multiplication only 0)
     -----------------------       
     11 10 01 11 (final sum)
```

Conclusion 11110111 != 11100111, I lost a bit.

Well, where is the pb ?

Best.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing something odd.

There are several common ways to multiply signed integers:

1. As you describe, you can first multiply the absolute values of the two multiplicands and then if the product is expected to be negative, negate it.
2. You multiply the integers using unsigned multiplication and then if one multiplicand is negative you subtract the other one from the most significant half of the product (and then you repeat the same symmetrically, checking the other multiplicand for less than 0, etc).
3. You use [Booth's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8192347/968261).